# Using GETDATE() in INSERT query, can it return that date back to me?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using the following code to insert a row into a database and set the date using `GETDATE()`. Without running a second separate query to pull that date back out, is there a way in the same query to have it return the date that it just inserted?

```
int resultCompletedDate = 0;

using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string updateQueryCompletedDate = @"UPDATE Conversions 
                                        SET CompletedDate = GETDATE(),
                                        Status = 'Completed'
                                        WHERE ID = @ID"; 

    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(updateQueryCompletedDate, connect);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", item1.ID);

    connect.Open();
    resultCompletedDate = Convert.ToInt32(command1.ExecuteScalar());
    connect.Close();
}
```

Comment: BTW, is an UPDATE query :)

Comment: Haha oops!  I missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a batch statement as the command-text. You don't need a verbatim string as you're not using backslashes or double-quotes.

```
DECLARE @completedDate datetime = GETDATE();
UPDATE Conversions SET CompletedDate = @completedDate, Status = 'Completed' WHERE Id = @id;
SELECT @completedDate;
```

Don't use `Convert.ToInt32`, just use `Convert.ToDateTime` instead.

Protip: use `using` instead of manually closing a connection, as right now your connection won't be closed if `ExecuteScalar` throws an exception:

```
using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection( ... ))
using(SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @completedDate...";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item1.ID);
    c.Open();
    DateTime completedDate = Convert.ToDateTime( cmd.ExecuteScalar() );
    return completedDate;
}
```

Comment: Cleaver, +1. OP can also use the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: @RubensFarias I think `OUTPUT` is cleaner, actually. Please submit that as a new answer :)

Comment: A much cleaner option would be having this batch sql code in procedure rather than having multiple sql statement.

Comment: @Rahul I disagree. I feel that Stored Procedures should not be used for short or trivial database operations.

Comment: You may but I don't see any smartness in sending a long text of SQL query over the network as well.

Comment: Downvote for @Dai - Hardcoding TSQL into your app will require more maintenance down the line when it requires a change - schema change, new logic, etc.  Changing a stored proc will be much easier than changing code, which may require deployment, etc.

Comment: @Greg DB Schema is often tightly wedded to an application's design and business logic, if you alter a sproc chances are you'll have to edit the application code too, which is why I feel using sprocs for trivial operations actually increases the maintenance burden as code is split-up in two different places.

Comment: In this application I would prefer to keep the possible changes in the program code instead of the database ( I have more control over the application than the database ).  I can see the merit of stored procedures though.

Comment: I see, i'm coming from an operations/production environment, where changes go through deployment processes, which should minimize code/risks.  If this is a client side thingy, i can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
using (var connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connect.Open();
    var command1 = new SqlCommand(@"
        UPDATE      Conversions 
            SET     CompletedDate = GETDATE(),
                    Status = 'Completed'
            WHERE   ID = @ID
            OUTPUT  INSERTED.CompletedDate", connect);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", item1.ID);

    resultCompletedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(command1.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the date to the query instead?

```
DateTime completeDate = DateTime.Now;

using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string updateQueryCompletedDate = @"UPDATE Conversions 
                                        SET CompletedDate = @CompleteDate,
                                        Status = 'Completed'
                                        WHERE ID = @ID"; 

    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(updateQueryCompletedDate, connect);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", item1.ID);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("CompleteDate",completeDate);

    connect.Open();
    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connect.Close();
}
```

The only difference is possible time zone differences between the client and server.

Comment: In this particular situation, differing time zones could be an issue